# modifying a cpp make file to .c file is not working

Tags: linux, makefile, subst

I am trying to modify a makefile that builds cpp to a c file, but I am running into some string substitution problem. I wonder if someone can point out the mistake.

here's a piece of the file:

```
SOURCES := \
lz4.c \
lz4frame.c \
lz4hc.cpp \
xxhash.c

OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(subst .c,.o,$(SOURCES)))
DEPENDS := $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(subst .c,.d,$(SOURCES)))

all: $(OUT_DIR)/$(LIB_NAME)

clean:

rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
rm -rf $(OUT_DIR)

$(OUT_DIR)/$(LIB_NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    @rm -f $@
    $(AR) cr $@ $^

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) -MMD -MF $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d -MP -MT'$(OBJ_DIR)/$*.o $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d' -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

.PHONY: all clean

-include $(DEPENDS)
```

but when I typed make clean I get this:

```
 Makefile:38: target `Release64/obj/lz4hc.opp' doesn't match the target pattern
```

or when I try to build I get this:

```
g++-4.6 -MMD -MF ./Release64/obj/Release64/obj/lz4hc.opp.d -MP -MT'./Release64/obj/Release64/obj/lz4hc.opp.o ./Release64/obj/Release64/obj/lz4hc.opp.d' -c -I../../../include -I../../../thirdparty/include/lz4 -std=c++0x -fPIC -O2 -m64  -o Release64/obj/lz4hc.opp
g++-4.6: fatal error: no input files
```

compilation terminated.

I think the issue is with this line, but I can't figure out the problem:

```
OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(subst .c,.o,$(SOURCES)))
DEPENDS := $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(subst .c,.d,$(SOURCES)))
```

thx!

Answer (score 2):

Your sources variable is:

```
SOURCES := \
lz4.c \
lz4frame.c \
lz4hc.cpp \
xxhash.c
```

Note the filename `lz4hc.cpp`.  Then you substitute `.c` with `.o`, that gives you a filename of `lz4hc.opp` which is exactly the error you see.

It's not clear if you really want a mix of C and C++ files, or if you just forgot to change the name of one of the files in the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can split C and C++ sources into separate lists, and use pattern rules to build your sources, e.g.:

```
SOURCES_C := \
lz4.c \
lz4frame.c \
xxhash.c
SOURCES_CPP:= lz4hc.cpp
SOURCES:=$(SOURCES_C) $(SOURCES_CPP)

OBJECTS_C := $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(subst .c,.o,$(SOURCES_C)))
OBJECTS_CPP:=$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(subst .cpp,.o,$(SOURCES_CPP)))
OBJECTS:=$(OBJECTS_C) $(OBJECTS_CPP)

DEPENDS_C := $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(subst .c,.d,$(SOURCES_C)))
DEPENDS_CPP := $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(subst .cpp,.d,$(SOURCES_CPP)))
DEPENTS:=$(DEPENDS_C) $(DEPENDS_CPP)

all: $(OUT_DIR)/$(LIB_NAME)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS)

$(OUT_DIR)/$(LIB_NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    @rm -f $@
    $(AR) cr $@ $^

%.o: %.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) -MMD -MF $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d -MP -MT'$(OBJ_DIR)/$*.o $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d' -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o: %.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) -MMD -MF $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d -MP -MT'$(OBJ_DIR)/$*.o $(OBJ_DIR)/$*.d' -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

.PHONY: all clean

-include $(DEPENDS)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a file that ends in `.cpp`, but your `subst` commands only deal with names that end in `.c`.  Try:

```
OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(subst .c,.o,$(subst .cpp,.o,$(SOURCES))))
DEPENDS := $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,S(subst .c,.d,$(subst .cpp,.d,$(SOURCES))))
```

Comment: Easier is to just use `basename`: `$(patsubst %,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(basename $(SOURCES)))`

Comment: @MadScientist: That will give you names like `lz4hc.cpp.o` -- probably not what you want.

Comment: No it won't.  `basename` strips off the suffix, any suffix.

Comment: @MadScientist: not the `basename` on my machine or any other machine I've seen -- basename strips the directory off, and optionally can strip a specific suffix, but only one specific suffix.  Try typing `basename foo.cpp` and see what you get...

Comment: Did you try my change?  You're talking about the POSIX program `basename`.  But in my example I'm using the GNU make function `basename`.  See: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html#index-basename :  _Extracts all but the suffix of each file name in names. If the file name contains a period, the basename is everything starting up to (and not including) the last period._